# What is the difference between these two theorems?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, set-partition

From Rosen's Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications, 3ed, chapter 6 p. 428-429:

[image: img]

It seems to me that both of them are talking about partitioning a set of `n` elements into `k` subsets.  It seems like it does not matter if the objects are distinguishable or not.  What exactly is different?

Comment: In the first theorem, we are not talking about partitioning a set into subsets.  We are instead talking about taking an arbitrary permutation of the $n$ objects.

Comment: But they end up having the same value?

Comment: Just imagine the objects in theorem 4 were indistinguishable. How could you distinguish two partitions at all? :-)

Comment: Yes, they end up having the same value. These are two different questions that happen to have the same answer.  It makes sense, then, that this answer is described in two different theorems.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, it is one way to look at it.  Bertsekas' Intro to Probability 2ed, p. 50 presents an anagram example.  Similar arrangements due the same characters being indistinguishable are seen as a way of partitioning the arrangements.  Thus, the permutations with a set of indistinguishable items can be reasoned to be a partition problem.

Comment: @J.Doe yes I understand that the first problem "can be reasoned into" a version of the second.  However, your question was "what is the difference between the two theorems", and the answer is still that they are about different questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transfer the formula of theorem 3 to theorem 4 as follows:

In how many ways can you label the $n$ distinguishable objects with $n_1$ labels $1$, $n_2$ labels $2$,$\ldots, n_k$ labels $k$?

Here the label tells in which box the object goes.

So, each arrangement of the $n = n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_k$ labels gives a way of assigning the objects to boxes. **But**, each permutation of the labels $n_1$, $n_2$, etc. does not change the box an object is assigned to.

Comment: Thank you so much for the insights.